# ZeroMQ 2 REQ/REP to allow nested talk

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

I want the following to happen:

There is a `main_socket`, where anyone can talk to.

Clients will send "READ" and wait for "OK" from Server before doing so.

Clients will send "WRITE", when they get a "OK", then it will mean they can do a write action. Everyone should wait for this. So I thought another REQ/REP channel, which is nested in the main loop. The server will start listening for a message on the `write_socket`, and when the client has written, it will send a message to the `write_socket`.

But this unfortunately does not work, and I have no idea why.

### server.py

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
main_socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
main_socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

write_socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
write_socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

print("ready to receive")
while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    print("server receiving main")
    message = main_socket.recv()
    print("server received main", message)
    if message == b"WRITE":
        main_socket.send(b"WRITE")    
        print("server receiving write")
        message = write_socket.recv()
        print("server received write", message)
        write_socket.send(b"OK")    
    else:
        main_socket.send(b"OK")
```

### client.py

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print("Connecting to main server…")
main_socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
main_socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

print("Connecting to write server…")
write_socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
write_socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")

print("starting")
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    print("client sending main", b"WRITE")
    main_socket.send(b"WRITE")
    print("client receiving main")
    message = main_socket.recv()
    print("client received main", message)

    print("client writing")
    print("writing...")
    print("client written")

    time.sleep(5)
    print("client sending write", b"WRITE")
    write_socket.send(b"WRITE")

    print("client receiving write")
    message = write_socket.recv()
    print("client received write", message)
```

This prints the following:

### server

```
ready to receive
server receiving main
server received main b'WRITE'
server receiving write
```

### client

```
Connecting to read server…
Connecting to write server…
starting
client sending main b'WRITE'
client receiving main
client received main b'WRITE'
client writing
client written
client sending write b'WRITE'
client receiving write
```

How can I make this case work?

Comment: Apparently it is about the specific port for the writer. 5556 did not work, 9999 did not work, but 6666 did work ~_~?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a hunch, but: the problem might be that it is possible to successfully bind `0.0.0.0:5556` even though there also is a bound socket say for `localhost:5556` i.e. `127.0.0.1:5556`.

In that case a socket bound to `0.0.0.0:5556` would continue to receive connections to *any other address except* `127.0.0.1`; and including IPv6, but the connection attempts to `127.0.0.1:5556` would be `accept`ed by another TCP server socket elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

### Your design concept is fragile in two principal layers:

so even if solving just the former will leave you absolutely powerless in the latter.

---

**[1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20[zeromq]) An Inherent Fragility of the Transport-Class :**
First, the associated transport-class level fragility ( not getting the previously released or externally used tcp-port ). Given this, one might move for some co-located architecture move the signalling/messaging services onto some non-tcp based transport classes, most probably some of the other `{ inproc:// | ipc:// | vmci:// }` but that does not solve the LAN/WAN-distributed operations scenario, plus, it would still contain a remarkable risk of not solving the second kind of fragility, that also requires some robust solution:

---

**[2] An Inherent Fragility of the `REQ/REP` Scaleable Formal Communitations Pattern :**
Any serious application design ought bear in mind, that the elementary ( primitive ) `REQ/REP` pattern is vulnerable for falling into a non-salvageable mutual dead-lock. [For **details** about this principal danger, kindly check my other posts on ZeroMQ, the `REQ/REP` deadlocks are quite frequent kind of collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20[zeromq]), but principally speaking here, if the application is going to be meant seriously for some kind of field deployment, then kindly forget to use the "naked"-`REQ/REP` primitive, otherwise you leave your application to a free-fall into a hierarchical-FSA deadlock, that cannot be self-detected from inside your application and thus cannot be reactively handled, or salvaged.

The good news is, there are many other simple pattern archetypes available in ZeroMQ, as building blocks, that allow one to integrate and fast-prototype a robust signalling / messaging application groundworks. So do not hesitate to empower your application with much richer inter-node signalling / messaging, that would not deadlock each other ( the less an any-to-any infrastructure-wide deadlock ... ).

Going this way, your both your **`try: / except:`** + **`assert`** Exception-handlers and non-blocking **`{ .recv() | .send() }`**-s would remain in control should some otherwise un-expected condition would appear ( and be sure **it** -- sooner or later -- **will appear** ) in-vivo.

Comment: Thank you for your concerns. Though I'm wondering what you would offer as an alternative? Also, do you have any other idea why my code worked on another port? Btw, this is where I imagined the code: https://github.com/kootenpv/justdb: as a permission granter to reads/writes to the file system (contrary to systems that have a database structure in the system).

Comment: Blocking + blocked-port rejections are quite common on hands-on prototyping, where some dirty ZeroMQ resources releases of resources may happen after an unhandled Exception - so the O/S side port-manager still assumes the port being used ( and the zmq.Context() indeed still having such resource allocated and in an in-use state ( neither .close() nor .term() happened to mediate a cleaning and release of resources for a gracefull exit ).